# C++ nested template classes syntax

Tags: c++, linked-list, iterator

I have a class `List` which is a fixed size, linked List, and inside that class there is another class `ListIterator` which points to a specific element of that `List`. My problem is the `c++` syntax I am not familiar with and the build errors from `gcc` are not helping me.

```
template<class T, int length>
class List {
public:
    //some stuff here
    //Row-struct

    template<class T>
    class ListIterator {
        public:
            ListIterator(int mPos, Row& mRow){pos = mPos; row = mRow;};
            T& operator *();
        private:
            int pos;
            Row& row;
    };

    typedef ListIterator<T> iterator;

    iterator begin();
private:
    int startIdx;
    Row storage[length];
};

template<class T, int length>
ListIterator List<T, length>::begin() {
    ListIterator *itor = new ListIterator(startIdx, storage[startIdx]);
    return itor;
}
```

I get the following errors:

> error:  shadows template parm 'class T'

1. How can I make this `typedef ListIterator<T>` work?
2. How can I use the same `T` I used for `List` for the Iterator?
3. Why does my `begin()` not work?

Comment: you don't have to do anything, just use it, it's known in this scope.

Comment: But I want to use `ìterator` in `ListIterator` as well as in `List` as typedef

Comment: `class ListIterator` inside `template <typename T> class List` has access to `T`, it doesn't need to be a template. You could even directly name it `class iterator` and skip the typedef

Answer (score 1):

Rename `ListIterator` template parameter `T` to something else, for example to `TInner`. Or make it a regular class if it can use `T` from outer class. Or move `ListIterator` outside of `List` class which would be a better idea since `ListIterator` does not actually do anything list-specific.

To fix `begin` function you need to use proper types:

```
template<typename T, int length> typename List<T, length>::iterator
List<T, length>::begin(void)
{
    iterator item_iterator(startIdx, storage[startIdx]);
    return(item_iterator);
}
```

Comment: `ListIterator` has to know a few things about the `List` (pointer, next element, previous elemen etc.)

Comment: @binaryBigInt Your code does not demonstrate it though.

Comment: Another options is a trailing return type

Comment: @VTT How do I access the object in my `main.cpp`? `List<int,2> list; List::iterator *it = list.begin();` doesn't work.

Comment: @binaryBigInt `begin` is supposed to return iterator, not a pointer to iterator. And you need to use proper type names (again), it should be `List<int, 2>::iterator it = list.begin();`

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot! But why do I get `uninitialized reference member in 'List<int, 2>::Row& {aka struct List<int, 2>::Row&}' [-fpermissive]` on my `ListIterator` ctor?

Comment: @binaryBigInt This error is not exactly related to the current question so you may want to ask a new question for this specific issue. Actually you should learn to understand error messages and to figure out what is causing them. You won't get far asking about every single straightforward error message on SO.